# Can you create a Solr collection in Railo with script?

Tags: coldfusion, solr, railo, cfml

ColdFusion 10 now supports this syntax for creating a Solr collection:

> cfcollection supports script style syntax:
>
> ```
> new collection().CREATE(collection="<collection_name>", engine="solr", path="<path to the solr directory>");
> ```

Is some sort of syntax like this available in Railo 4?

I keep getting an error saying:

**invalid component definition, can't find collection**

If not, can this be set up as a UDF so that I can call it from a script-based component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest beta of Railo 4.0 currently implements the following objects:

- Feed
- Ftp
- Http
- Mail
- Query

So, the answer is no - **there is no "collection" object**.
(You can of course raise a [feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO) for adding that.)

However, **there is an alternative** - in Railo pretty much all the tags can be reproduced in script form.

You can write:

```
<cftagname attributes />
```

as

```
<cfscript>
    tagname attributes ;
</cfscript>
```

Or for tags with bodies:

```
<cftagname attributes >
    ...
</cftagname>
```

becomes

```
<cfscript>
    tagname attributes
    {
        ...
    }
</cfscript>
```

So simply factor your [cfcollection](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/TAG%3aCFCOLLECTION) tag in this form and it should work fine.

Comment: Are you kidding?  I'm so looking forward to trying this out tonight.

Comment: Works with custom tags too. :)

Comment: There is an example of calling this in script at http://railodocs.org/index.cfm/tag/cfcollection